# Настройка OOM Killer на убийство Java процессов

Tags: linux, archlinux

Периодически процессы Java разжираются до больших объемов, можно ли как либо настроить OOM Killer что бы он их убивал, а не вешал систему с 100% дисковым IO. ArchLinux, java процессы запускаются от пользователя 1000 из скрипта start.sh, юниты systemd не подходят так как мне нужен STDIN что бы отдавать комманды.
Если можно указать родителя - вообще замечательно.

Comment: а oom обязателен? может просто ограничить выделение памяти через cgroups?

Comment: Я бы попробовал через pam_limits

Answer (score 0):

Быстрый гуглёж привёл к [вариантам](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process):

1. Использовать модифицированный [timeout](https://github.com/pshved/timeout)
2. Использовать ulimit -m *нужный_лимит*;
3. Использовать cgroups